# Broken TVs and repairmen: a probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

To paraphrase the question as best as I can

> There are $4$ repairmen in a village. $k$ people break their TVs. Each person chooses at random which of the repairmen to send their broken TVs to. What is the probability that $i$ repairmen are sent broken TVs, for $i=1,2,3,4$?

I want to solve this problem for a general $i$, without reference to which number $i$ is.

My progress so far amounts to noting that $4^k$ counts the number of possible permutations. Then $4^k/k!$ counts just the number of TVs each repairmen is sent. This is weird for large $k$, though, so I think it is wrong.

I guess I should find how to count the number of possibilities of how TVs are assigned to repairmen, but I am stuck on this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, there are $4^k$ possible assignments of repairmen to TVs.  More generally, for any subset $S$ of the repairmen, there are $|S|^k$ assignments such that all of the TVs go to repairmen in $S$ (but not necessarily giving a TV to each repairman in $S$.)  Let $f(S)$ denote the number of assignments such that exactly the repairmen in $S$ get TVs, and let $p(i)$ denote the probability that exactly $i$ repairmen get TVs.  Note that
$$p(i)=\frac1{4^k}\sum_{S\subset\{1,2,3,4\}\atop |S|=i}f(S),$$
which by symmetry can be written as
$$\frac1{4^k}{4\choose i}f(\{1,\cdots,i\})$$

If $|S|=1$, then $f(S)=1^k=1$, so $p(1)=4/4^k=1/4^{k-1}$.

For an $i$-subset $S$, [inclusion/exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) gives us the formula
$$f(S)=\sum_{0\le j<i}(-1)^j{i\choose j}j^k=i^k-\sum_{0<j<i}(-1)^{j-1}{i\choose j}j^k;$$
that is, the number of mappings **onto** $S$ is the number of mappings **into** $S$,
minus the mappings into $(i-1)$-subsets of $S$, plus the mappings into $(i-2)$-subsets, and so on.

Thus, if $|S|=2$, we have $f(S)=2^k-2(1^k)=2^k-2$, so $p(2)=6(2^k-2)/4^k$.

For $|S|=3$, we have $f(S)=3^k-3(2^k)+3$, so $p(3)=4(3^k-3(2^k)+3)/4^k$.

And for $|S|=4$ we have $f(S) = 4^k - 4(3^k) +6(2^k) - 4,$
and $p(4)$ is this quantity over $4^k$.  As a sanity check, it's worth verifying that $p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4)=1$.